# Excel VBA - Copy and Paste

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get a VBA coding that will search for cells formatted as a date, and for all date formats, again search for particular text above it and copy it to the row for which the date cell is.

To illustrate, below is a sample of my data that I'm attempting to address. For any cell in column C that has is formatted as a date, I'm hoping to have the code find the Customer number (cell C2) and customer name (D2) and copy to columns A and B on the applicable row.  The problem comes in because many of the customers in my data have more than one voucher, so I can't hard code it to simply be two rows above the cell that has a date.  I hope I'm making sense!

```
Customer account Name
1001010 Internal : Sales Admin (9900) 
Date         Voucher
12/7/2011    CINV00000980
1/26/2012    CINV00001011
2/9/2012     CINV00001050
3/6/2012     CINV00002003
3/13/2012    CINV00002067
```

I'm trying to use nested Do loops right now (see below), and obviously it isn't working.  The code is running, but no copying/pasting is happening.

```
Sub ARAging() 
   Dim row As Integer
    row = 2
    finalrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Do

    If Range(Cells(row, 3), Cells(row, 3)).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy" Then
        Do
        If Range(Cells(row, 3), Cells(row, 3)).Value = "Customer account" Then
        Range(Cells(row - 1, 3), Cells(row - 1, 4)).Select
            With Selection.Copy
            End With
        End If
        row = row - 1
        Loop Until Range(Cells(row, 3), Cells(row, 3)).Value = "Customer account"

        Range(Cells(row, 1), Cells(row, 2)).Select
            With Selection.Paste
            End With
    End If

row = row + 1

Loop Until row = finalrow
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Wow, my example data didn't copy well.  Columns A and B are blank. Column C has the text "Customer account", the customer account number, "Date", then five dates (C1:C8).  I'm hoping that for each of the five dates, the code will search for the text "Customer Account" above it and return the applicable customer account number for each of the five dates.  Hopefully this clarification helps.

Comment: Just noticed: the dates in your sample data are m/d/y format but your code tests for d/m/y format.  In my answer I do not test for format although not for this reason.

Answer (score 2):

I think this code does what you want.  I hope I have included enough comments to explain my code.  Come back with questions if necessary.

```
' Option Explicit means every variable must be explicitly declared.  Without
' it a misspelt variable name becomes an implicit declaration.  This can be
' a very difficult error to find.
Option Explicit

Sub ARAging()

  ' On a 32-bit system, the native size is what Excel calls Long.  So integer
  ' variables are slower than long variables.

  ' My style is to start a variable name with its type and then add classifiers
  ' to identify its purpose.  This means that when I return to this macro in
  ' six or twelve months, I know what the variables are.  If you do not like my
  ' style, develop your own or develop one with colleagues.  Consistent names
  ' are a godsend during maintenence.
  Dim acctNumCust As String
  Dim rowCrnt As Long
  Dim rowFinal As Long

  With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ' I avoid ActiveSheet unless I want the user to be able to run the macro
    ' against a worksheet of their choice.

    acctNumCust = ""
    rowFinal = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For rowCrnt = 2 To rowFinal

        ' In .Cells(R,C), C can be a number or a column code.
        ' If I am accessing a single cell, I do not need to make it into
        ' a range since .Cells(R,C) is a range.

      If .Cells(rowCrnt, "C").Value = "Customer account" Then

        ' Since I know column C is "Customer account", I do not need to
        ' save it.  Save the value of column 4 in a variable not the
        ' scratchpad.
        acctNumCust = .Cells(rowCrnt, "D").Value

        ' I do not like testing for the formatting.  What if the user changes
        ' it to dd-mmm-yy?

      ElseIf IsDate(.Cells(rowCrnt, "C").Value) Then
        .Cells(rowCrnt, "A").Value = "Customer account"
        .Cells(rowCrnt, "B").Value = acctNumCust

      Else

        Call MsgBox("Cell C" & rowCrnt & " is neither """ & _
                                    "Customer account"" nor a date", vbOKOnly)

      End If

    Next rowCrnt

  End With  ' Worksheets("Sheet1")

End Sub
```